# Having multiple Media Queries in CSS sheets

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

If one adds two responsive gadgets say,

A navigation bar with a media query like this in the navigation style CSS file

```
@media screen and (max-width : 760px){

    nav ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    nav li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    nav ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav .show-menu {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

and a responsive slideshow with the media query >

```
@media screen and (max-width: 65.3125em) {
    .description,
    .tiltview {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .tiltview {
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0.3;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 33.75em) {
    .description {
        font-size: 1.1em;
    }

    .slideshow > nav span {
        width: 20px;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 24em) {
    .slides {
        height: 320px;
    }

    .description {
        font-size: 1em;
        padding: 1.4em;
    }

    .no-csstransforms3d .tiltview.col,
    .no-csstransforms3d .tiltview.row {
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

**My question is , when opening the website on a mobile device the responsive effect DO NOT work** and the site remains fullscreen , why is that ? Is it because I have different media queries on different CSS sheets with different widths ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding this `meta` tag to your `head` of your html page?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: forgot all about it on this page, this solved the problem (Y)

Comment: Awesome! Please mark my answer correct when you can.